# Random output from loop in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I'm having a problem with a loop in R. The code is supposed to iterate over the rows of a column in a data frame, but I'm noticing it's selecting the rows randomly and I'm not sure how to fix this.

This is the code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cbg_frame)) {
 cbg_list = cbg_frame[i,]
summary(str_length(cbg_list)
}
```

for context, cbg_frame is a data frame with only one column. I'm trying to iterate over the rows in that column.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To help others help you, please include a sample of the data: paste the output of `dput(cbg_frame)` into the question. And include the expected output. See [MRE]

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
Your example is missing a paranthesis

```
summary(str_length(cbg_list))
```

Assuming that this didn't cause the error on your side, I've created a reproducible DF. Since you only have one column you could use `apply()` to iterate over each row:

```
#creating reproducible dataframe with one column
cbg_frame <- data.frame(foo = month.name)
#iterating over each row
apply(cbg_frame, 1, function(x) {summary(str_length(x))})
```

EDIT: You didn't really explain what the code should achieve. Maybe you want to make a summary of your results? In this case you could try this:

```
#creating reproducible dataframe with one column
cbg_frame <- data.frame(foo = month.name)
#iterating over each row
cbg_list <- apply(cbg_frame, 1, str_length)
#and summarizing the results
summary(cbg_list)
```

Comment: So the code is supposed to index over each row in the data frame. It should take the values in each data frame and perform the tasks written in the rest of the code on that value. The problem now is that it's selecting each row randomly when it goes through the column

Comment: You don't have to iterate over the rows at all. You can perform most tasks on each row of a dataframe. For example ```str_length(cbg_frame[,1])``` applies the function ```str_length``` to every row of the 1. column of the df (as indicated by [,1]) and returns it in the same order.